# What type of boundary condition(s) do I need to define for a process with diffusion of tracer concentration?

Tags: boundary-conditions

I want to simulate the diffusion of initial dye concentration in a small estuary with a 2D depth averaged model. Would a radiation boundary condition for concentration of tracers alone be enough or do I need to define any additional conditions at the open boundary?